# laravel task scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-5.1, laravel-forge

I want to know if the task scheduler of laravel forge override the settings in my Kernel Class file because I don't understand which one it will use 
because I set in the dashboard of laravel forge daily and in my kernel class file a command to run only it's  the first of the month like this

```
$schedule->command('log:demo')->daily()->when(function(){
            if(Carbon::now()->toDateString() == Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->toDateString())
            {
                return true;
            }
});
```

I put daily() function here to check everyday if it's the first of the month 
and I know that it will not be executed if the function doesn't return true
but with laravel forge it's executed everyday , I think forge doesn't look at this file
[image]

Comment: you have what setup to run everyday on forge ?

Comment: @lagbox the setup is to run LogDemo class that contains the code to be executed

Comment: "I set in the dashboard of laravel forge daily" ... what did you set daily ?

Comment: @lagbox it's easy my friend laravel forge gives radio boxes to check
I checked daily choice

Comment: What did you set to run daily ? what ? I dont use Forge and there is no publicly accessible documentation for it.

Comment: @lagbox i will put an image to undersatnd

Comment: Forge is using the scheduler you have setup or that scheduled task wouldn't get executed at all. I just setup a task to run every minute using this `when` `return Carbon::now()->day == 1;` and it works as expected locally.

Comment: @lagbox thanks mate I solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the schedule:run to run EVERY MINUTE - this checks what you have in your Kernel and if something needs to be ran on that minute it will run that particular task (job).

For example if I have a task that runs once per/hour and another that runs once per day. I would only need ONE scheduled task in Forge: schedule:run - THEN in my Kernel I would have

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('report:hourly')->hourly();
     $schedule->command('report:daily')->daily();
}
```

Make sure that your commands are registered with the Kernel:

```
 protected $commands = [
     Commands\Hourly::class,
     Commands\Daily::class,
];
```

Comment: anything really bad happen if you DON'T run it every minute? got some crazy problem and client wants to turn down the frequency of the cron.